# DbContext Changes Date which is Stored in Database Upon Object Graph Creation

Tags: entity-framework-6

This question is now a curiosity, more than anything. Dates will be the end of me.

Using EF 6.

I am storing a date and in the same http request, pulling the object back out of the database.

When I look at the SQL which EF sends, the milliseconds of the date in question which are returned are the same as that which are stored in the db (expected behaviour).

BUT, when EF deserializes that into the object graph in memory, the milliseconds are different.

So, I save '2018-10-16 21:46:22.293'
SQL retrieves '2018-10-16 21:46:22.293'
EF deserializes to 2018-10-16 21:46:22.294 !

I created a workaround by hitting the db with a raw ADO.NET query that gets the exact date ('2018-10-16 21:46:22.293').

Even weirder, if I use a fresh DbContext and grab the whole object with that, the date is fine i.e. '2018-10-16 21:46:22.293'

So, it is only when I use the same DbContext that save the data, to retrieve the data that the date gets rounded (or something).

Anyone seen this weird behaviour? Is there a better fix than either raw SQL (ado.net) or a fresh DbContext?

Cheers

Comment: Interesting! What happens if you bypass the EF cache by appending `.AsNoTracking()` to your retrieval query?

Comment: @AlistairFindlay Sorry for belated reply. It looks as though using AsNoTracking does solve the problem. I should have used that anyway, as it is a straight query with no manipulation going on (no updates etc.). Will do some further testing, but early indicators are good.

Comment: Great - let us know how you get on...

Comment: @AlistairFindlay Sorry, I forgot to come back to you on this. AsNoTracking did solve the problem. Further testing confirmed this. Happy to mark that as the answer (of course) if you post as such.

Comment: Posted as answer - thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can bypass the EF cache by appending `.AsNoTracking()` to your retrieval query.